# Is there a way to use Expression Blend 2012 Line Tool in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, draw, expression-blend

Is there a way to use Expression Blend 2012 Line Tool in Visual Studio 2012?
The actual Line Tool in VS draws a blank rectangle.

Comment: I don't think the Line & Shape controls were added until 2013 via power pack but 2012 I think you're better off with Blend. On that note, I think you're better off with Blend for nay design type work.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge and what I have read and studied so far, line tool is for Expression Blend only where as it can't be used in VS IDE. For design purpose you should use Expression Blend (Blend for VS).

Regards

Comment: Thank you saad. Anyway I found a solution and now I'm able to draw Lines at design time in a way similar (but not equal) to Blend.